# ifdown: interface eth0 not configured

Tags: linux, networking, ifconfig

Can someone explain this behavior?

After boot, I run these commands:

```
ifdown eth0
ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
```

If I run another time the

```
ifdown eth0
```

command, I'm answered

```
ifdown: interface eth0 not configured
```

even if the interface is up and running:

```
ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500  metric 1
    inet 192.168.0.239  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 fe80::fadc:7aff:fec4:aa9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether f8:dc:7a:c4:0a:a9  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 277  bytes 27140 (26.5 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 36  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 120  bytes 14650 (14.3 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I'm running a yocto linux embedded machine (Variscite SOC imx-6).

Comment: Don't mix & match commands. Either use ifup & ifdown or use ifconfig. Using ifconfig does not preserve settings & will be lost at reboot. The ifup & ifdown uses a file to preserve settings & that is the preferred way of operating.